# Error ZIP file not provided - autoUpdate on mac using electron-updater dmg

Tags: electron, electron-updater

I have a mac dmg target installer set up with electron-updater, when my app detects update I get an error in the logs saying that `ZIP file not provided`. Not sure how to solve this?

EDIT: In the [docs](https://github.com/lidel/electron-builder/blob/3201878fdb0c0c548d53b81742dd126f003aa8d5/docs/configuration/mac.md) it says "Defaults to default (dmg and zip for Squirrel.Mac). Note: Squirrel.Mac auto update mechanism requires both dmg and zip to be enabled, even when only dmg is used. Disabling zip will break auto update in dmg packages"

I tried setting target to `default` and I got a different error that it could'nt find `<installerName.zip>`, although only a dmg file was created.

Im using:

```
"electron": "14.0.1",
"electron-builder": "^22.13.1",
"electron-updater": "^4.4.6",
```

Answer (score 3):

In the build settings, I removed the `"dmg"` target and replaced it with `"default"`. I made sure that both installers `<installerName.dmg>` and `<installerName.zip>` have been created (otherwise the update for the dmg won't work) and uploaded them to storage location.